# How does one perform DWT using R Studio?

Tags: r, dwt

Hello new to R Studio and having challenges in decomposing data using DWT to a daubechies series of 4 (db4) and n.levels = 4 to a data set of 72 varaiables and 1 observation(Depth(m))

Encountering an error

```
Depth <- dwt(up.sample(Data[, c("DEPTH (m)")], f - 1), wf="la8", n.levels=4, boundary="periodic")
```

> Error in matrix(rep(y, (f - 1) * n), nrow = f - 1) :
>   object 'f' not found

Comment: Hi Edu.. what's the object f in your code? did you assign it? Can you also list the packages or libraries used (is it  waveslim)

Comment: Hi argument f supposedly represents frequency in upsampling..dont know what it means to be honest...need help in upsampling the data set